# Hide text at onClick using css

Tags: html, css

My Code:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="show" type=checkbox>
<div id="content">
<p>i need help</p>
<label for="show" style="color: red;">Hide</label>
</div>
<label for="show" >read more</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
#show,#content{display:none;}
#show:checked~#content{display:block;}
```

This code will show/hide the Content when clicked on "read more"
But I also want to hide the "read more" when its clicked using only css without javascript.

How can I hide it?
Thanks in advance!!

```css
#show,#content{display:none;}
    #show:checked~#content{display:block;}
```

```html
<input id="show" type=checkbox>
<div id="content">
<p>Any help would be appreciated</p>
<label for="show" style="color: red;">Hide</label>
</div>
<label for="show" >read more</label>
```

Comment: It works exactly the same way for the `label`, as it did for `#content` - only that you want to set `display:none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```css
#show,#content{display:none;}
#show:checked~#content{display:block;}
#show:checked~#more{display:none;}
```

```html
<input id="show" type=checkbox>
<div id="content">
<p>Any help would be appreciated</p>
<label for="show" style="color: red;">Hide</label>
</div>
<label for="show" id="more">read more</label>
```